# Automatisation of isochrone map creation in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, isochrone

I need to measure the area of isochrones for a big number of points, for different time thresholds and for different means of transport.

I've been using the plugin isochrones in OSM tools with QGIS 3.4.4 but it takes a long time if there are many points. It also crashes sometimes. Besides, it needs to change the threshold manually at each step.

Is there any way to automate this processing and to avoid crashing?

Comment: You should see the plugin code and run each calculation in a new `QgsTask`. You need to program it